# Making overview with linked detailed maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, map-overviews

I want to create 4-5 detailed maps, and then an overview map that has rectangles that marks the locations of the detailed maps. Best case would be if the rectangles were linked to the detailed map.

I have managed to make the overview and the rectangles, and think I know how to make the detailed maps one by one. The rectangles are drawn manually on the overview map.
All layers that I plan on using are in the same QGIS project.

The final product that I hope to create would be the overview map on the first page, followed by the detailed maps. The overview would have links to the detailed maps, click on the rectangles to open the right detailed map.

Is there a way to link the detailed maps to the overview in QGIS 2.8 print composer?

I want the overview to show the extents of all of my detailed maps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to create an overview map for multiple detail maps in Print Composer. The workflow is as follows (see the [user docs on this topic](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#overviews) as well):

1. Create the detail maps
2. Add another map item and set it to overview
3. Configure the overview map by adding the detail maps to its settings

Answer (score 6):

With help of @underdark’s answer, I figured out how to make the overview!

The problem was how, in the third step, to make the overview show all of my detailed maps in one map.

I made a map (step 2) and then I added one overview for each of my detailed maps using the plus button. For each of my detailed maps, I checked the box 'lock layer for map item'.

Then I zoomed out on the map canvas in QGIS, and chose layers to be shown on the overview map.

Then I went back to the Print Composer, and with the overview map frame activated I clicked 'Set to map canvas extent'.

My overview map now shows where my detailed maps are located.