# Generating map sheets and index page in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, indexing

I have a project in QGIS and would like to print it out in multiple pages. I know how to set the pages one by one (pages 1,2,3), but I would like to know if there is an easy way to do the index page with the overview of the whole project?

Here is a picture to clarify my problem:

[image]

This overview could also follow in each pages legend and for example highlight the current page.

I'm new to QGIS.

Comment: Do you want the index map as page 4? Or do you want an index map on each of the three pages of your atlas?

Comment: Firstly, I want to have it in the front page, so in this example it would be "page 0". If it's possible, it would be nice to have smaller index map also on all pages in the legend.

Comment: I think you should create a polygon layer that has the bounding boxes of your pages - 0 for the front page, 1,2,3 for the individual pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is two separate questions, both of which are answered elsewhere. The trick is just knowing what search terms to look for. So I'll summarize the answers, and include links to better documentation elsewhere.

Question 1: **How to add a map showing the full extent to a series of maps?**

Answer: To add the full extent map as the first page of the atlas, simply add an feature to your Atlas layer that covers the entire extent of the map. I'm assuming you've already set up an Atlas. If not, see the [Atlas section of the QGIS manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_output.html#generate-an-atlas).

Question 2: **How to add an overview map to each page of the print composer?**

Answer: Use the "overview" feature in the print composer. For more details, see the answer to [Making overview with linked detailed maps in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146383/making-overview-with-linked-detailed-maps-in-qgis)