# How to create an index map of atlas features in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I realise that this question has been asked before ([Making overview with linked detailed maps in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146383/making-overview-with-linked-detailed-maps-in-qgis)), however I am still unable to figure out how to create an index map of atlas features in the QGIS map composer.

Basically, I have a line and I have five atlas maps showing the extent of the line, and to show where which map corresponds to the line a I need five overviews on a map with numbers on them, which will look similar to below:

[image]

I've created five overviews, but as all of these must be set to correspond to the main map frame, all of them show the overview for which ever atlas feature is selected at the time, rather than appearing as separate index tiles.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Make a polygon layer with rectangles that exactly match the extent of the map on each atlas page. Display these rectangles on a simple map (not controlled by the atlas). Depending on what your atlas features look like, you might be able to use your atlas layer for this.

Answer (score 3):

Add two maps to your print layout.

1. Make one map controlled by the atlas. This is your atlas feature "closeup" map. It will be different on every page of the atlas.

   [image]
2. Make the other map *not* controlled by the atlas. This is your overview map. It will be the same on every page of the atlas.

   [image]

Here are the first two pages of an example atlas. Notice that the map on the left changes, while the map on the right is the same in both pages.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create another (bigger) page frame that spans all the maps. Somplistically a page zero would show the whole area with the map frames from 01 to 12. . .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).